# MongoDB not working on deployed Meteor project

Tags: mongodb, azure, meteor, database

I've been working on a project with some friends using MongoDB and Meteor. It was working fine until we deployed it, we noticed the Mongo DB was not connecting to the Meteor app.

We are using:

- Azure's Virtual Machine server
- Meteor for development
- Mongo for our database (Hosted in Azure's Document DB, different location from the Meteor's Azure VM)
- Meteor up (mup) for deployment

We did notice that when we run the project locally with meteor, we need to specify the MONGO_URL on the same command (*MONGO_URL="MongoDB connection string" meteor*) if not, it doesn't connect to the db. This may be happening on the website, although we have specified the mongo url in the mup as follows:

```
env: {
  ROOT_URL: 'IP',
  MONGO_URL: '<URL>'
},
```

We have checked everything and not sure how to proceed, any feedback would help.

EDIT: Specify server locations

Comment: What does your mongodb.log look like?

Comment: Is your app running on the same VM as MongoDB? Or is it running somewhere else (e.g. Web App)? Please edit your question with more details.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I added some details, let me know if there is a specific piece of info that will help with the issue

Comment: @MattShirley The DB is never accessed, it's not even an error in the connection

Comment: Well, you just disclosed that you're not using MongoDB - you're using DocumentDB (with mongo support). They're not 100% equivalent. In any case, you should include the connection string you're using (minus the 'real' credentials and instance name, of course).